# Audio DOM created inside vuex is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to create an audio element that would be used for playing all audio urls I have on all routes, I think it's a useful approach for a SPA (Am I right?). So I've decided to declare *new Audio* in the state of vuex that I can easily reuse and update just mutate the src property of audio object. And it works, but the problem appears when I want to get properties of this audio object such as currentTime and duration for building audio progress bar and it's not reactive. How to solve this problem?

```
const state = {
  audio: false,
  object: new Audio()
}

// getters
const getters = {
  audio: state => state.audio,
  percentage: state => (isNaN(Math.round((state.object.currentTime / state.object.duration) * 100))) ? 0 : Math.round((state.object.currentTime / state.object.duration) * 100)
}

// actions
const actions = {
  playAudio ({ commit, state }, previewUrl) {
    commit('play_audio', previewUrl)
  },
  stopAudio ({ commit, state }) {
    commit('stop_audio')
  }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
  play_audio (state, previewUrl) {
    state.object.pause()
    state.object.currentTime = 0.0
    state.object.src = previewUrl
    state.object.play()
    state.audio = {
      preview_url: previewUrl
    }
  },
  stop_audio (state) {
    state.object.pause()
    state.object.currentTime = 0.0
    state.src = ''
    state.audio = false
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue only officially supports plain JavaScript objects as reactive data; things like DOM elements and other such objects won't be and cannot be made reactive.

One way around this is to store just the `audioSrc` string and `isAudioPlaying` boolean values in the Vuex store and then manage the `Audio` object in the root Vue component. You can watch `audioSrc` and `isAudioPlaying` for changes and then call methods on the `Audio` object in response to those changes.

```js
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    audioUrl: null,
    isAudioPlaying: false,
  },
  
  mutations: {
    play(state, url) {
      state.audioUrl = url
      state.isAudioPlaying = true
    },
    
    pause(state) {
      state.isAudioPlaying = false
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  
  created() {
    this.audio = new Audio()
  },
  
  watch: {
    '$store.state.audioUrl'(url) {
      this.audio.pause()
      this.audio.src = url
      this.audio.currentTime = 0
      this.audio.play()
    },
    
    '$store.state.isAudioPlaying'(playing) {
      if (playing) {
        this.audio.play()
      } else {
        this.audio.pause()
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    play(url) {
      this.$store.commit('play', url)
    },
    pause() {
      this.$store.commit('pause')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.3/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="play('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Ludwig_van_Beethoven_-_Symphonie_5_c-moll_-_1._Allegro_con_brio.ogg')">Play Beethoven</button>
  <button @click="pause">Pause</button>
  
  <div>audioUrl: {{ $store.state.audioUrl }}</div>
  <div>isAudioPlaying: {{ $store.state.isAudioPlaying }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I've tried your solution and just achieved the point where I was, I can manage play/pause audio. But how can I get reactive property of audio such as currentTime or duration?

Comment: @fitzima use this event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event